# Python selenium masked field

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, maskedtextbox

I'm tying to fill masked phone field `+7(___)___-__-__` with python and selenium

```
<input type="tel" name="PHONE" id="phone" class="js-phone-masked">
```

My code:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('phone').click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_id('phone').send_keys(Keys.HOME, '9353232222')
```

but it filled only firs 2 digs 9 and 3. 
[image]

How i can fill all of this masked field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that either there are multiple elements for that phone field, or the underlying javascript is somehow preventing the entire string from writing. You could try sending each digit individually perhaps:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('phone').click()

for digit in '9353232222':
    driver.find_element_by_id('phone').send_keys(Keys.END, digit)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: This is a clever solution but I wouldn't wait a full second for each digit... you could change that to `time.sleep(0.1)` or something to make it faster.